# Spring security with angular

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have simple project with spring security, i taked it from [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/).
I put it to GitHub repo ([mySource](https://github.com/DanStopka1985/task1)).

Pages in this project - jsp.
I want to remake this functional to angular (authization and welcome page), and escape from jsp.
I want do it as simple as possible.

Help me, please! Thanks!!

Comment: And how your attempts going? Can you show us some?

Comment: Now i'am using velocity, I did not know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not shown any of your effort so far so as an idea I can suggest you to use  [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) pages instead of `JSP` in same project. And then you can simply apply angularJS code in `Thymeleaf` pages. You can get the idea from [this](https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs) repository.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! very helpful!